# How can i group data by column that i create for query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I group data by "work experience"

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Name and Ln",
    MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hire_date) / 12 AS "work experience"
FROM 
    HR.EMPLOYEES 
WHERE
    MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hire_date) >= 15 * 12
```

How can I group my query by that column work experience that I create? I need to write group by "work experience' or what

[image]

Comment: please don't add data as image, also how should the result look like?

Comment: column with age should be in increasing order

Comment: an ORDER has nohing to do with a GROUP BY so post the original data and the result you expect from the presented data.  Why not add `ORDER BY "work experience" ASC`?

Comment: I agree with @nbk. You don't need `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Group By clause is not required here.

As the requirements mentioned in the issue, you can use 'distinct' as following:

```
SELECT distinct(round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hire_date) / 12,0)) AS work_experience,          
CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS Name_and_Ln            
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES 
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hire_date) >= 15 * 12
order by work_experience desc;
```

If the above code doesn't resolve your issue, please update the required output you need.